# AWK incrementing on column number

Tags: loops, awk, increment

I have a large file and some repetitive tasks to execute on columns: in plain language, most tasks would like to

```
do from i=0 to 9
(col$30+i) = (col$10+i) + (col&20+i)
```

I would expect at every loop:

i=0
col$30 = col$10 + col$20

i=1
col$31=col$11+col$21

...
i=9
col$39=col$19+col$29

I tried explore tags  like 'loop over columns', 'increment over column', but nothing came up easily. I could write it for every i, but was wondering if there was a magic trick out there that would be more efficient and transposable to other similar cases.
thanks!

dummy data

```
col10 col11  col20 col21  col30 col31

… 2 42 … 12 1 … 14 43
… 2 83 … 22 1 … 24 84
… 2 45 … 33 4 … 35 49
… 3 61 … 36 3 … 39 64
```

so at iteration 1, col30 is populated with the correct sums, at iteration2, col2 is populated with the correct sum ... etc...

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your question for better understanding of question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh I have added a pic of dummy data- I hope it's Ok

Comment: Request you to please post data in text form only, so that we could copy it and could copy/paste it for testing etc.

Comment: Your pseudocode straightforwardy translates to `awk '{ for(i=0; i<=9; ++i) $(30+i) = $(10+i) + $(20+i) }1'`

Comment: `{ sum = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { sum += $i; } print sum}' will print the sum of all fields for each line.

Comment: thank you all for taking the time. plenty of good ideas - apologies if my pb was not clearly stated. @tripleee I adopted your answer! cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `colN` you mean the *N*th column, your pseudocode straightforwardly translates to

```sh
awk '{ for(i=0; i<=9; ++i) $(30+i) = $(10+i) + $(20+i) }1'
```

Your dummy data looks like those are column *labels* in which case you have to parse the first line and figure out which column number corresponds to which label.  For your example,

```sh
awk 'NR==1 { for(n=0; n<=NF; ++n) if ($n ~ "^col[123][0-9]$") a[$n]=n }
    { for(i=1; i<=9; ++i) a[30+i] = a[10+i] + a[20+i] }1'
```

Answer (score 1):

as a test harness - you can take it further:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=0; i<=9;i++) printf("$%d = $%d + $%d\n", i+30, i+10, i+20)}' /dev/null
$30 = $10 + $20
$31 = $11 + $21
$32 = $12 + $22
$33 = $13 + $23
$34 = $14 + $24
$35 = $15 + $25
$36 = $16 + $26
$37 = $17 + $27
$38 = $18 + $28
$39 = $19 + $29
```